# Issue with SFSafariViewController on 3DTouch (Pop State)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement the Peek and Pop functionality in a `TableViewController`, so that when I 3DTouch any of the cells, it shows me a preview of the `SFSafariViewController` they'll take me to on tapping them. The peek functionality works just fine, but as soon as it moves to the pop state, it doesn't give `SFSafariViewController` in the [desired state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVoL3.png) but instead end up showing the navigation controller from the previous view, and a poorly sized view showing the `SFViewController` [(Image Here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoJrk.png).

This is how I've programmed the peek and pop functionality inside my `TableViewController`:

```
extension MyBlogsTableViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) {

            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyBlogsTableViewCell

            let destinationViewController = SFViewControllerToExplore(indexPath.row)
            destinationViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

            previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

            return destinationViewController
    }
    return nil
}

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
}

private func touchedView(view: UIView, location: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    let locationInView = view.convertPoint(location, fromView: tableView)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, locationInView)
}

private func SFViewControllerToExplore(index: Int) -> UIViewController {
    var destinationController: SFSafariViewController

    destinationController = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: identifierOfLinks[index])!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)

    return destinationController
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. So in the following code :

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
     navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
}
```

I shouldn't actually be using pushViewController, I should instead, be using presentViewController

Corrected Code:

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
     navigationController?.presentViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```